# I would like to set up rfc5766-turn-server in Ubuntu 14.04, can anyone give me the set of steps listed all together ? I am doing it in AWS EC2

Tags: webrtc, amazon-ec2, stun, turn, apprtc

I have tried to install and set up rfc5766-turn-server in AWS EC2 but unable to do it as I do not see a proper flow of work or command line for that, can someone help me about this ? I need to set it up in Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Any fast help will be really helpful for me.

Comment: take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32113146/3074768)

Comment: I tried. And having errors.

Comment: what are the errors?

Comment: The installation is done, but when I am trying to get the TURN URL, I am unable to understand what should I put. Any suggestion ?

Comment: you are unsure of how to run the TURN server, or how to use the TURN url in your application?

Comment: How to use to use the turn URL. and where from I can get that TURN URL ?

Comment: check this out ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34982250/how-to-establish-peer-connection-in-web-app-using-coturn-stun-turn-server/34983853#34983853

Answer (score 1):

do an ssh login to your ec2 instance, then run the below commands for installing and starting the turn server.

commands for installing turnserver:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install make gcc libssl-dev libevent-dev wget -y                   # for installing modules required by turn server
mkdir ~/turn && cd ~/turn                                                     # creating temp directory
wget turnserver.open-sys.org/downloads/v3.2.5.9/turnserver-3.2.5.9.tar.gz       # downloading the TURN source code
tar -zxvf *.gz                                                                  # extract
cd turn* 
make 
sudo make install                                                               # installing the rfc5766
cd ../.. && rm -rf turn                                                         # cleaning up
```

command for starting the TURN server:

```
turnserver -a -o -v -n -u user:root -p 3478 -L INT_IP -r someRealm -X EXT_IP/INT_IP
```

assumptions:
    your ip, internal ip = EXT_IP, INT_IP
    desired port for listening: 3478
    single credential username:password = user:root
    realm: someRealm

in your WebRTC app, you can use trun server like:

```
{
    url: 'turn:user@EXT_IP:3478',
    credential: 'root'
}
```